# How to give permission to user groups rather than only a user?

Tags: permissions, group-policy

I opened `mmc.exe` and from `File>Add/delete snap-ins` I added Group policy object editor for a specific user. From here I an give and deny access to many settings(around 100 in my case) on the computer. But I have so many accounts (around 6 users in my case) on the computer and I have to edit each and every settings for each user.

Instead I want to add Group policy object editor for a User group so that once I edit the settings for a group I can simply add all the users to that group and don't have to edit the settings for each users individually.

But I can only add individual users in group policy object editor, is there a way around?

Comment: Ideally you would have a domain controller and set group policies through Active Directory.  This stuff is not intended for Workgroups.

Comment: @paradroid do you have any idea how to export those settings and import it again in future?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I just use Active Directory.  Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2 is pretty cheap.  Stick it on an HP Microserver.

Comment: @Lifestohack What OS is the computer?  Is this question related to one computer or multiple?  Do I correctly assume the computer(s) are NOT part of an Active Directory domain?

Comment: @Twisty there are many computers and the computers are not part of any ADD. They are a localcomputers not connected to each other or to any networks. May be editing a registry on one comupter and copying it to others computers may work???